# XCode does not see new C++17 feature

Tags: c++, xcode, build, c++17

I try to increase C++ version in XCode MacOS BigSure(11.0.4).
[image: settings]
And optional header is found good but when I try to use `std::optional` I get an error `No template named optional in std`. In optional header I find implementation but part with

```
namespace std {
    template <class T> optional;
...
}
```

is under the /**/.

I increase version in settings to C++17 and standard library to libc++(LLVM with C++11 support). clang version is 12.0.5.

How can i fix this trouble?

Comment: "_I increase version in settings to C++17_" - Are the project settings viewable as XML or JSON or something else readable by humans? If so, you could add your project settings to the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, fix.

Comment: Is it possible to see the full project configuration as plain text (not a picture)? It should be in the project folder somewhere. When it comes to the library version, do you have any other options than the one you've selected?

Comment: Worked for me.  I'm using the current Xcode 13 version.  You may want to check [feature testing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) to see if your version has `std::optional` support.